# Do browsers repeatadly download identical images?

Tags: images, download, website

I have a set of connected websites, all with the same images in the header. When a user clicks a button to get to a new site, the header should stay the same while the content changes. Does the users browser repeatedly download the header images every time a new site is visited, even though the images are the same? Or does the browser only download new, encountered images?

Answer (score 1):

If the different sites all use a common image URL, like

```
<img src="http://imagehost.example.com/foo.png">
```

then the browser will only download one copy. If each site hosts its own copy, like

- `a.com` uses `<img src="foo.png">` (which really refers to `http://a.com/foo.png`)
- `b.com` uses `<img src="foo.png">` (which really refers to `http://b.com/foo.png`)

then the browser won't know that they're the same image, and will download multiple copies.

Not necessarily the cleanest, but if you don't have a separate image hosting domain or use a third party image host, then you could just have both sites refer to one site's copy (e.g., both sites could use `<img src="http://a.com/foo.png">`).

Comment: so if I only save one copy of the image on the server, this image will only get downloaded once, even if it is used on several html documents, correct?

Comment: It's based on the URL, not the server. If the same server hosts two different sites (like `a.com` and `b.com`), but each site's code refers to the same file on disk, the browser doesn't know that. It only knows based on the URL.